# How to get a variable from a Nexpect method?

Tags: node.js, expect

I am running Nexpect from inside a Docker and I need to get the IP of another docker container, so I ssh into the host and I run a method using Nexpect to get the IP address, but I don't know why the method is returning null, here is the code of the method:

```
exports.getIP = function(username){
   var nexpect = require('nexpect');
   var ip;

   nexpect.spawn("ssh core@172.17.8.101 docker inspect  --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' " +  username)
         .expect(" ")
         .run(function (err, stdout, exitcode) {
             if (err || !err) {
                  console.log("stdout = " + stdout);
             }

           ip = stdout;
    });

  console.log("ip = " + ip);
  return ip;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's asynchronous, you're returning the value straight away when it hasn't been assigned within the nexpect method. You need to add a callback to tell it when to return the result.

```
exports.getIP = function(username, callback){
   var nexpect = require('nexpect');

   nexpect.spawn("ssh core@172.17.8.101 docker inspect  --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' " +  username)
         .expect(" ")
         .run(function (err, stdout, exitcode) {
             if (err) {
                 callback(err);
             }

           ip = stdout;
           callback(null, ip);
    });
};
```

You can then do

```
require('module')
    .getIP('username', function(err, ip){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(ip);
    });
```

You can also use [promises](https://github.com/then/promise) for this.

```
var Promise = require('promise');

exports.getIP = function(username) {
    var nexpect = require('nexpect');

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        nexpect.spawn("ssh core@172.17.8.101 docker inspect  --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' " + username)
            .expect(" ")
            .run(function(err, stdout, exitcode) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    ip = stdout;
                    resolve(ip);
                }
            });
    })
};
```

And

```
require('module')
    .getIP('username')
    .then(function(ip) {
        console.log(ip);
    }, function(err) {
        throw err;
    })
```